# FBGraph and FQL use to get the friends contact number and emailID in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I am using Facebook API to get the contact number and email id of friends, I worked on fbgraph and fql and uses all queries from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/, but in forum page of Facebook I found there is no way to get the contact number and email ID.

I also used the extended permission of the Facebook API but I didn't find anything.

If anyone know about it then please give the answer ...

Answer will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code with the users access token

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=" + token;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("get", url, true);
req.send(null);
req.onerror = function () { alert("Error"); };
```

Then you will find the req.responseText has all the user information you are after. You can also get the user access token once they login.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "email" permission when the user authenticates

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"permissions",nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
[permissions release];
```

Then, when the user has logged in, get the "me" from the graph:

```
[facebook requestFromGraph:@"me/" withDelegate:self];
```

You get the information from the "requestDidLoad" callback method:

```
if([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]){
  // do stuff w/ user info
}
```

The id is:

```
 [request objectForKey:@"id"];
```